# Track image clicked on to change inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find a way to track the image that I click on in order to change the inner HTML of the element above where all the images are placed. For example when I click on St. John The Baptist I would like the title to switch to St. John The Baptist.

Currently, the function I have enlarges the image I click on and makes it go back to regular size again after clicking a second time. Whether in this function I implement it or in another I do not care, but I do need the enlarged image to be the one that is affecting the inner html of the element above.

```js
const highlight = () => {}; //

const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.main-textbox-about-saints');
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.style.height === '30rem' && e.target.style.width === '20rem') {
    e.target.style.height = '35rem';
    e.target.style.width = '25rem';
  } else {
    e.target.style.height = '30rem';
    e.target.style.width = '20rem';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="main-textbox-about-description">
  <h1 class="main-textbox-about-description-text">St John the baptist</h1>
</div>
<!------------------------------------>
<div class="main-textbox-about">
  <div class="main-textbox-about-saints">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-peter-2176658_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-1" onclick="highlight();" id="peter">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-stylianos-2191792_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-2" onclick="highlight();" id="stylianos">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-demetrius-2176682_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-3" onclick="highlight();" id="demetrius">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/archon-2086750_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-4" onclick="highlight();" id="archon">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-andrew-2176673_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-5" onclick="highlight();" id="andrew">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-john-the-baptist-1652345_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-6" onclick="highlight();" id="john">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-paul-2176669_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-7" onclick="highlight();" id="paul">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to store the title in your `img` elements, preferably as a `data-*` attribute, then you can use `getAttribute()` to fetch it and set as title

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: ALso you already have a click event. You can delete the inline highlight function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the text you want to display from somewhere. Storing it in a `data-*` attribute makes the most sense. Beyond that, you'll set up a `click` event handler on the parent `div` of all the images and then just set the text within that callback.

```js
const highlight = () => {}; //
const mainText = document.querySelector("h1.main-textbox-about-description-text");

const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.main-textbox-about-saints');
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.style.height === '30rem' && e.target.style.width === '20rem') {
    e.target.style.height = '35rem';
    e.target.style.width = '25rem';
  } else {
    e.target.style.height = '30rem';
    e.target.style.width = '20rem';
  }
  
  // Update the text
  mainText.textContent = e.target.dataset.caption;
});
```

```html
<div class="main-textbox-about-description">
  <h1 class="main-textbox-about-description-text">St John the baptist</h1>
</div>
<!------------------------------------>
<div class="main-textbox-about">
  <div class="main-textbox-about-saints">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-peter-2176658_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-1" onclick="highlight();" id="peter" data-caption="Peter caption">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-stylianos-2191792_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-2" onclick="highlight();" id="stylianos" data-caption="Stylianos caption">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-demetrius-2176682_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-3" onclick="highlight();" id="demetrius" data-caption="Demetrius caption">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/archon-2086750_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-4" onclick="highlight();" id="archon" data-caption="Archon caption">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-andrew-2176673_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-5" onclick="highlight();" id="andrew" data-caption="Andrew caption">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-john-the-baptist-1652345_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-6" onclick="highlight();" id="john" data-caption="John caption">
    <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-paul-2176669_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-7" onclick="highlight();" id="paul" data-caption="Paul caption">
  </div>
</div>
```